# Integrate WhatsApp Product Catalogue to Whats App business api account

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, whatsapi, facebook-business-sdk

I am using the WhatsApp Business API to use my chatbot and I needed to connect the Facebook product catalog to the configured WhatsApp number. Does anyone know what I can do to associate a catalog with a WhatsApp account and if it is possible to use the catalog response in the WhatsApp API for consumption?
I'm developing a chatbot for restaurants and I wanted the user to be able to place an order through the WhatsApp Business catalog and from there the chatbot would get the rest of the information.
I already have a catalog set up and a working WhatsApp number, however, when I associate the menu with the registered phone number, the catalog does not appear on the WhatsApp profile of the registered number.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Cloud API or are you working through a BSP? Displaying products in Whatsapp catalog, is enabled by a separate method. I know for sure that some BSPs do it automatically, but most of the time, you need to figure out the settings to display the "Catalog" menu itself.
So after linking Commerce Manager and WA - you need to ask your provider to enable display 'store'.
The second problem that awaits you is that on the API side you won't see any information about the products except for the product ID. That is, if a user places an order, the API will not tell you the name of the product. This limitation can be overcome the hard way - you need to create your own application to connect to Commerce Manager and pull in real-time information about the product through Meta Commerce API.
Unfortunately, Meta has not yet complemented the Business API in this direction. I really hope that someday they will add methods for working with goods.
For now, you can either use unofficial solutions (not related to Meta), or use services that have already integrated the Commerce API and allow you to fully work with goods.

Comment: In this case, I am the BSP actually. So I will provide my customers catalog to theirs whatsApp business API app. In this case I still must create my own app?